# Postgres 9.2 find, compare and replace two values in column

Tags: sql, sql-update, postgresql-9.2

Hi i am trying to run a query to find two values in the same column, compare them and set the highest value to both and I am get a bit confused.

I can not work out how to do it prettily so I have gone for an ugly approach and am still lost.

I have a table with data in a bit like this

```
Fruitname   Fruitvalue
Apples        11
Pears         10
Oranges       2
```

I want to be able to query the table and get the values for Apples and Pears. I then want to replace the value of Apples or pears based on the highest value

Like this

```
Fruitname   Fruitvalue
Apples        11
Pears         11
Oranges       2
```

The code below gets me the highest value

```
SELECT MAX (fruitvalue) 
FROM fruit 
WHERE fruitname IN ('apple','pear')
```

But I can work out how to turn the result into a variable and assign it to the fruitname.

for example

```
$variable = SELECT MAX (fruitvalue) FROM fruit WHERE fruitname IN ('apple','pear')

UPDATE fruittable SET fruitvalue = '$variable' WHERE fruitname = 'apple';
UPDATE fruittable SET fruitvalue = '$variable' WHERE fruitname = 'pears';
```

Comment: Please show us your table definition some sample data and the expected result of the UPDATE statement based on the sample data.

Comment: thanks i have edited the above to include sample data and result. Sorry fo the poor formatting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a variable, you can use the select to get the maximum value directly in the `update` statement.

```
update fruittable 
   set fruitvalue = (SELECT MAX (fruitvalue) 
                     FROM fruit 
                     WHERE fruitname IN ('apple','pear'));
where fruitname in ('apple', 'pear');
```

This works because the sub-select returns exactly one row.

Comment: thanks so much, the solution looks so simple now I see it written down